# Why doesn't C#'s String.Join use StringBuilder at one point?

Tags: c#, stringbuilder, .net-standard, standard-library

As can be seen [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs), one of `String.Join`'s overloads works with raw pointers and uses something called `UnSafeCharBuffer`. Why is this? Is it a performance optimization?

Comment: Yes; that's for performance.  All of `string` is very heavily optimized.

Comment: `StringBuilder` still has to copy to a string as the final step. Writing directly to the return string skips that overhead.

Comment: Also `StringBuilder` has a default size that may not be entirely consumed, and continues to increase by that buffer every time you exceed.  So three or four smaller strings being created is still a lot faster.

Comment: @Greg: Three or four smaller strings? Anyway, you can create a `StringBuilder` with an exact initial (and maximum) capacity.

Comment: @Ry- But that still is converted into a `string`.  So `StringBuilder` will consume a percentage of memory defined, just to consume more memory when it becomes a `string`.  Boils down to this http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/stringbuilder.html

Comment: @Greg: Correct. What do you mean by “three or four smaller strings” though?

Comment: That smaller immutable strings consume less memory than the overhead generated by StringBuilder often.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Is a performance optimization?

Yes.

In general you should expect that unsafe code is either for low-level unmanaged language interop or for performance optimization. In this case it is the latter.

This then suggests the question:

> Why not use the same techniques for StringBuilder?

Different scenarios can be tuned using different optimization techniques; StringBuilders are optimized for their scenarios.

The scenarios are different in several ways. `Join` knows ahead of time exactly how many bytes will be returned; `StringBuilder` does not. `Join` knows that the resulting string will be generated *exactly once*, but a `StringBuilder` has to support the create, append, `ToString`, append, `ToString`, ... workflow efficiently.  And so on.

Comment: but there are three other overloads/implementations of `String.Join` that actually use `StringBuilder`... You're only talking about a specific one.

Comment: @Adrian: I made the reasonable assumption that the original poster was talking about the implementation that does not use a stringbuilder, because the question was about that implementation, and the question was "Why doesn't C#'s String.Join use StringBuilder?" Why would anyone assume that the OP was asking about an implementation that does use StringBuilder, given that question?

Comment: I agree one can infer this from the question, although i would say that it (especially the title) sounds like there was only *this one* implementation, and no other

Comment: @Adrian I agree that the title is a little misleading. I'll revise it.